# webpack SASS bundle and create multiple files

Tags: webpack, sass

I'm changing from gulp to webpack, and I'm with some problems compiling SASS.

I managed to not putting inline (although I would like to select if it would need to be inline or not, but will deal with that after I solve this).

So I have 2 .scss files that I need to import and to be created separately, and not to auto-import in the .html would be great too.

i've tried:

- entry: [ ] approach,
- tried with ExtractTextPlugin.extract and
- with MiniCssExtractPlugin.
- I've searched a lot and with no good results.

My current webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
//const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
//const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  //const isDevMode = options.mode === "development";
  return {

    module: {

      rules: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,

          use: [{
                loader: "html-loader",
                  options: {
                    minimize: true,
                    conservativeCollapse: false,
                    removeScriptTypeAttributes: false,
                    removeStyleTypeAttributes: false,
                  }
              }]

        },

        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          //use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              use: [
                { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                {
                  loader: "css-loader",
                  options: {
                    minimize: true
                  }
                },
                {
                  loader: "postcss-loader",
                  options: {
                    plugins: [
                      require("autoprefixer")(),
                      require('cssnano')({
                        preset: 'default', 
                            discardComments: {
                              removeAll: true,
                            }
                      })
                    ],
                  }
                },
                {
                  loader: "sass-loader",
                }
              ]
          //})
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html"
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
        filename: "[name].[hash].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
      })
    ]
  };
};
```

files to create the .css from:

```
./src/css/styles.scss
./src/css/teste.scss
```

expected result should be

```
./dist/assets/css/styles.css
./dist/assets/css/teste.css
```

Comment: where is your entrypoint on this? Webpack expects to read all the dependencies from your entrypoint and your entrypoint is preferable to be a javascript file. You don't actually need to move from gulp if you just want to compile css.

Comment: Default index.js. I will need more things but was doing a step at a time.

Comment: styles.scss and test.scss are imported on your index.js file?

Comment: Yes, they are. Shouldn't be?

Comment: Nono, they should, i'm just double checking!

Comment: i guess i will go back to gulp and use only webpack for react. Damn, when they said its really complicated to get this working with "custom" configurations its really true.